# How do I connect UI elements to IBOutlets and IBActions?

Tags: xcode, user-interface, interface-builder, xcode5, uielement

I'm trying to connect a UI element in a window to my app's controller/delegate using the Assistant editor, but there is no option to create a new IBOutlet/IBAction when dragging from the UI element to the interface file.

The File's Owner of the window is NSWindow, and its not my main menu (which is a NSMenu on a NSStatusItem, if that helps). The main menu's UI elements works perfectly fine. When my application is run, the window is opened when expected with all UI elements in place, but because I can't connect them, they don't call any methods and are not changed.

No connection is made when dragging from the interface file to the UI element (even when right clicked) or to the Connections Inspector or the other way around. I've tried regular dragging and control dragging too.

How can I connect the UI element to its IBOutlet (for changing state programmatically) and IBAction (for receiving the user's change of state)? Am I not selecting the UI element correctly? Do I need to be dragging to a different spot?

On the Connections Inspector, where should I be dragging from/to?

Is there any other way I can connect it that should work?
Is there other things I can try?

[image: Example of no new connection being made]

EDIT: When I control drag to an already existing outlet, it gives me the option to make a binding.

EDIT2: Upon further troubleshooting, I've found that this applies to all UI elements, not just checkboxes.

Comment: Are you dragging to the file's owner?

Comment: @Abizern No, the file's owner is NSWindow (the default), and I'm dragging to my app's main class.

Comment: That's the problem then.  You can only connect this way to the class that matches the File Owner.

Comment: @borrrden Embarrassingly simple. If you want the bounty, you should probably make an answer :)

Comment: Eh, @Abizern had the problem figured out already so it belongs to him.

Comment: @borrrden is that actually common practice? I thought it was supposed to be a first come serve thing. <s>no wonder all those people were so mad</s>

Comment: Not really, I'm just too lazy to write a proper answer right now haha.

Comment: @borrrden I was struggling with answering this for like six hours, and I had tried to change the file's owner to the app's delegate a few times, but I was actually setting the window to the class of the app's delegate (where it says Custom Class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect your outlets to the File's owner for this to work.